# How to combinate tuples in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to combinate following tuples?

`(1, 2); (5, 6) ; (3, 4)`

The solution should be:

`(1, 5, 3); (1, 5, 4); (1, 6, 3); (1, 6, 4); (2, 5, 3); (2, 5, 4); (2, 6, 3); (2, 6, 4)`

At the starting point I got `m = 3` tuples. The number of tuples increases with every iteration and after every iteration a new tuple for recombining will be added. So after the first iteration I get:

`(1, 2); (5, 6); (3, 4); (9, 10)`

Then combinate those 4 tuples etc.
 Is there a possibility to do this dynamically until a stopping condition hits?

Comment: what code have you written?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: try `from itertools import product; result = [i for i in product((1, 2),(5, 6) ,(3, 4))]`

Comment: is *combinate* a word?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "do this dynamically"? Do you know how to find your "combinations" (which are actually *products*) for a fixed number of tuples? Are you asking how to use those "combinations" and a new tuple to find the "combinations" of your old source tuples plus the new one? If so, why not just work from the source tuples? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: for our test case this example is just generated by nested for loops. But we dont know how many tuples we get from the data until the stopping condition kicks in. For loops are just not very practiable for our case

Comment: If the `for` loops are your only problem, use just use `list(itertools.product(*L))` on your list of source tuples. No loops needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `product`

```
from itertools import product
a = (1, 2),(5, 6) ,(3, 4)
result = list(product(*a))
```

Comment: @RoryDaulton Is list comprehension really a `for`-loop? Isn't it a mere list construction written in another form?

Answer (score 0):

yes, its possible

```
from itertools import product
for i in range(your_limit):
    your_tuples_container.append(your_new_tuple)
    result = list(product(*your_tuples_container))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion, thus only needing several `for` loops for any input dimension:

```
l = [(1, 2), (5, 6), (3, 4)]
def cartesian_product(d, current = []):
  if not d[1:]:
    yield [i+[b] for i in current for b in d[0]]
  else:
    yield from cartesian_product(d[1:], [i+[b] for i in current for b in d[0]])

print(list(cartesian_product(l[1:], list(map(lambda x:[x], l[0]))))[0])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 5, 3], [1, 5, 4], [1, 6, 3], [1, 6, 4], [2, 5, 3], [2, 5, 4], [2, 6, 3], [2, 6, 4]]
```